# Protect against identity provider downtime in AspNetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am having a situation where I have an IdentityServer4 as identity provider of my AspNetCore app, the IdentityServer4 server some times has downtime and I want to protect my app against this. I would like to know if there is a good way to check the availability of the IdentityServer4 before the login challenge in order to branch to a local login flow, or if there is any other good solution to this problem.

Comment: Load balancing / failover. Is your solution. If you need a service to always be up, you need it to be replicated across regions with a load balancer in front of it. If you use containers with orchestration, this is mostly handled for you out of the box, i.e. you can deploy your Identity Server app as a container to something like Azure Kubernetes Service, and set a minimum and maximum number of pods, letting Kubernetes handle the heavy lifting. For geo-redundancy, you can deploy one or more nodes of your cluster into different regions.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisPratt your solution would be ideal, but in my situation I don't control the IS4 instance, I must solve the problem for now in my app.

Comment: Using Identity Server supplants any local login flow. If you can't optimize the availability of your Identity Server instance, then your only real solution is just temporarily disabled account functionality while it's down.